# Conflicts with jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm a new JQuery programmer, here is my head code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function myfunction(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide();
    };
  });
  $(document).ready(myfunction);
</script>
```

this script works perfectly, but when i add these other three scripts in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file/lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

che console error gave me:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on '$(document).ready(myfunction);' line.

what is the error? Is a conflict problem?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to just one of those three js files? That'll make it easier for others to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Are you sure your script works perfectly? My console returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) `

Comment: are you adding them after the jquery? if not, there's your problem

Comment: If I recall correctly, both jQuery and prototype assign themselves as `$`. Try use jQuery's `noConflict()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prototype.js also uses the global `$` variable. You need to make sure they don't conflict with each other by using the `jQuery` variable instead:

```
// wrap it up
(function($) {
  function myfunction() {
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide();
    });
  };
  $(document).ready(myfunction);
})(jQuery);
```

You can also just replace all jQuery `$` uses with `jQuery`, but the method above is generally simpler to implement and maintain.

Comment: now my script works correctly but the others have render problem. The lightbox shows at the bottom of the page

Comment: @PhantomFav Make sure you use `jQuery` for code that uses jQuery, and `Prototype` for code that uses Prototype. Never use `$` globally since it's conflicted.

Comment: Oops, i forgot the css, my bad, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 6):

*jQuery* defines a function called `$` that you are trying to use.

*prototype.js* also defines a function called `$` and overwrites the one from jQuery.

Use `jQuery` to refer to the jQuery function instead of `$`.

Comment: And you might want to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to make jQuery revert its claim of the `$` global.

Comment: The j should be lower case.